# Dataframe to a dictionary as some columns in a list as keys and one as value

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
col1    col2    col3
A       X       1 
B       Y       2
C       Z       3
```

I want to convert this into a dictionary with col1 and col2 in a list as key and col3 as value. So, the output would look like this:

```
{
 ['A', 'X']: 1,
 ['B', 'Y']: 2,
 ['C', 'Z']: 3
}
```

How do I get my desired output?

Answer (score 1):

There are several restrictions while defining dictionary keys. Lists or dictionaries can not be a dictionary's keys, because they are mutable - unhashable. Meaning they can change and we can not track them, sort of like they do not have a unique hashcode. Thus, you can not set lists as dictionary keys. But,  you can set **tuples** as dictionary keys. **Tuples** are very similar to lists. Let's make your dataframe again:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col1':['A','B','C'],'col2':['X','Y','Z'],'col3':[1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now, we have the same dataframe. Now, let's use list comprehension method to go (iterate) through all the rows of the dataframe, while selecting column1 and column2 as tuple keys and column3 as values:

```
my_dict = {(df.iloc[i,0],df.iloc[i,1]): df.iloc[i,2] for i in range(len(df))}
```

Now, you have the following output:

```
my_dict = {('A', 'X'): 1, ('B', 'Y'): 2, ('C', 'Z'): 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this using pandas methods:

After creating the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'X', 1], ['B', 'Y', 2], ['C', 'Z', 3]],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Set the index to the columns that form the dictionary keys, select the column for the values and convert it to a dictionary:

```
df.set_index(['col1', 'col2']).col3.to_dict()
```

To get the required result:

```
{('A', 'X'): 1, ('B', 'Y'): 2, ('C', 'Z'): 3}
```